# Add onScroll hook to third party reactJS components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a third party reactjs component called `react-syntax-highlighter` and I want to develop a logging feature that tracks users' scrolling behavior for research purposes.

However, since I'm using a third party component like this:

```
<div className={this.props.className}>
       <SyntaxHighlighter language= {supportedLanguages.includes(this.state.language) 
         ? this.state.language : null}
         style={androidstudio} showLineNumbers={true}
         lineNumberStyle={lineNumberStyle}>
         {this.props.fileName ? this.state.code : 'Select a file'}
     </SyntaxHighlighter>
   <div className="select-language input-field">
      {languageSelection}
   </div>
 </div>
```

I'm not sure how to add a hook to track the scrolling event on this component from the outside. Can someone help me take a look please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `height` for the `SyntaxHighlighter` component, then add `overflow-y: scroll`. Finally, add `onScroll` event listener to `SyntaxHighlighter`:

```
  <SyntaxHighlighter
    className={"class1"}
    onScroll={() => console.log("scrolled")}
    language="javascript"
  >
    {'code string'}
  </SyntaxHighlighter>
```

`class1` CSS:

```
.class1 {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is a working example (open `console` at the bottom to see the result):

https://codesandbox.io/s/jj16m0nqm5

Comment: You may still need to pass onScroll to an actual dom element for it to work.